# CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled ios6

Tags: objective-c, core-location, ios6

Im fairly new to Objective-C and I was trying to find a user's location. Below is what I have but there is a parse issue with `(![cLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])`.

I think it was deprecated for iOS6 but i cant find what to use instead.

```
- (void)updateLabels {
    if (location != nil) {
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",location.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",location.coordinate.longitude];
    } else {
        self.longitudeLabel.text = @"";
        self.latitudeLabel.text = @"";

        NSString *statusMessage;
        if ([lastLocationError.domain isEqualToString:kCLErrorDomain] && lastLocationError.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
            statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
        } else {
            statusMessage = @"Error Getting Location";
        } else if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) { //Problem lies here
            statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
        } else if (updatingLocation) {
            statusMessage = @"Searching...";
        } else {
            statusMessage = @"Press the Button to start";
        }

        self.messageLabel.text = statusMessage;         
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I see you updated the original code in your question with the required fixes. This is bad form. Now if someone looks at your question and the answers, it doesn't make any sense. Never modify your original question once answers have been provided. You can add to the question, but don't modify the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class method `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled` has not been deprecated so should work fine.

Have you added the relevant import to your class?

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Comment: i had #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> in my .h and i also put it in .m but still not working

Comment: OK. What exactly is the error/warning that Xcode is displaying?

Comment: i figured it out i had a to stopUpdatingLocation and left out the startUpdatingLocation which uses locationServicesEnabled so that was the problem all along thank anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra '[' on the line with the problem and the method is wrong. You have:

```
if (![[CLLocationManager locationServiceEnabled])
```

It should be:

```
// Remove extra [ and spell method name correctly
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
```

Comment: i changed the simple syntax errors but no luck also im getting no intellisense on locationServicesEnabled

Comment: @ThomasMannion Your question was about the syntax issue, that's it. I gave you the answer. 14 hours later, another answer is posted that doesn't answer your original question and you mark that answer as the accepted answer. Strange.